# XAMLWriter fails for DataGrid columns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml-serialization

I am using XAMLWriter to serialize some controls. It works well for other controls, but not for DataGrid. First thing, it can not serialize DataGrid columns, which is very annoying(if somebody has a solution, great!), so I manage to find workaround.
This code:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
DataGridTextColumn dgTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
dataGrid.Columns.Add(dgTextColumn);
XamlWriter.Save(dataGrid);
```

Produces this output: `<DataGrid />`

No columns at all!So, I figured out that I can add columns as items:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
DataGridTextColumn dgTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
dataGrid.Items.Add(dgTextColumn);//notice the change
XamlWriter.Save(dataGrid);
```

And I got this output, which is enough for me:

```
<DataGrid >
     <DataGridTextColumn />
</DataGrid>
```

Than I can manually add `<DataGrid.Columns>` and `</DataGrid.Columns>`

Can anyone explain me why is XAMLWriter behaving like this, and is there a way to successfully serialize DataGrid columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns and Items are not the same thing. Items property is for the data content of the datagrid. In your second code sample you are adding Columns as items.

See following for explanation why columns are not serialized and a solution: [Cannot serialize DataGridTextColumn in DataGrid with XamlWriter.Save](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/51d09642-4aaa-4401-b2e7-73c897286b71)

Comment: Yes I am, intentionally, because my columns are not serialized. So, I add them as items, and than add <DataGrid.Columns> and </DataGrid.Columns> lines around items and they are now columns. But that is not my problem...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is: [Cannot serialize DataGridTextColumn in DataGrid with XamlWriter.Save](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/51d09642-4aaa-4401-b2e7-73c897286b71)
your case.

Comment: I tried XamlServices.Save and got following exception: "Save of deferred-load content threw an exception." What does that mean? What is deferred-load content?

Comment: Here is something from MSDN:  "Important:
XamlServices is not the recommended XAML reading or XAML writing API set if you are processing Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) types, or types based on WPF. For WPF usage, use System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader for reading or loading XAML; and System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter for writing back XAML. These classes use System.Xaml APIs internally in their implementation; however, they also provide support for WPF-specific concepts that influence the nature of XAML reading and writing, such as optimizations for dependency properties."

Comment: So, we are back to the beginning. XamlServices.Save method does not work in my case, while XamlWriter.Save works for everything except DataGrid columns.